# I am getting a different port number than I use

Tags: java, networking, port

I have 2 java programs, Server and Client.

I am trying to connect the client program to the server program using java socket programming.

Here is the Server program :

```
public class ServerX {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(987);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InetSocketAddress isa1 = (InetSocketAddress) s.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    System.out.println(isa1.getPort()); 
    ss.close();
  }
}
```

And here is the Client program :

```
public class ClientX {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Socket s = new Socket("ip of the server", 987);
      s.close();
   }
}
```

I expected that `isa1.getPort()` in the Server program gives `987`, but it actually gives `52532` instead.
So what is the problem, and what `53532` means?

Comment: `isa1.getPort()` returns the port opened on the client side. A socket connection needs two opened ports, one on the server side, one on the client side. You usually don't choose the value of the port opened on the client side, it is chosen by your system amongst the available ports, `53532` in your case.

Comment: @Arnaud
What is the need of using 2 ports number?

Comment: This is just how things work, it is a communication between two ports.. Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301075/client-use-high-port-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a full duplex communication protocol it means both side of an established connection allowed to send and received data.

so server is listening on port 987 but client side also need a port on it's own side to receive data that is being sent from server side and about the connection in case of ClientX, server will listen to incoming requests on port number 987 but if want sent something as reply to ClientX will write on port 53532 of the connection

Comment: Yes that is, but I also have 2 questions, why can server not reply client on the same port number, i.e.  `987` ? And is there a way in Java that I can change `53532` ?

Comment: 1- TCP supposed to create duplex communication thats why there are two different class in java ServerSocket and Socket. the difference is ServerSocket is designed to serve multiple incoming requests whereas socket is  established session between two machine. as you might notice accept() method receives client request and create a fresh Socket and returns to client. if it doesn't create a fresh Socket object per request it wouldn't be able to server more than one client.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on requirement over here. But if you wish to perform a sanity check on Static port and usage of Java is not a pre-cursor, then I feel below script must help you. I had referred to Python Docs (https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/socket.html) for getting help in past for one of my project requirement.

```
'''    Simple socket server using threads
'''
import socket
import sys
HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 61901 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket bind complete'
#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
s.close()
```

Herein `PORT = 61901` can be replaced with required port.